# How to add buttons and zooming to Carousel in Kivy?

Tags: python, button, carousel, kivy, zooming

I have Carousel widget for sliding images.
 
I need to know how to add buttons beneath images.
 
And the main is zooming the images (like in Kivy's example: ./examples/demo/pictures).
This is my code (it loads several images from "image" folder):

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy

import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from glob import glob
from os.path import join, dirname
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel
from kivy.factory import Factory

class MyClass(App):

    def build(self):    
        # the root is created in pictures.kv
        root = self.root

        # get any files into images directory
        curdir = dirname(__file__)

        carousel = Carousel(direction='right')
        for filename in glob(join(curdir, 'images', '*')):
            image = Factory.AsyncImage(source=filename, allow_stretch=True)
            carousel.add_widget(image)
        return carousel

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyClass().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Buttons
Please use a layout to hold the buttons and picture widgets

2. Zooming:
 The Picture class is derived from the Scatter widget. This widget allows rotation and is used in the 47th line in main.py as in:
       picture = Picture(source=filename, rotation=randint(-30,30))
This gives every instance of the Picture class, picture, the ability to be rotated and scaled(zoom in or out) width double-touch events
```